# Reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 without cd or usb. (Windows installed aside it)

Tags: grub2

My Ubuntu installation is currently ... a mess. There is no other way to put it.

So I want to reinstall ubuntu. Unfortunately I lost my install dvd a while ago and I don't have another dvd. I also don't have an usb-stick to install it to. I did read something on the wiki that you can use minimal installation (I have a 700 mb cd available).

However that doesn't appear to be the solution as that will leave out the gui and all the other things that I need. So I'm looking for a way to install it.

I also read something about unetbootin, but I have a bad experience with it so I am a little hesistant to use it.

I have Ubuntu and Windows XP installed on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your old Ubuntu's GRUB still loads correctly, then you might be able to just copy the whole iso to your hard drive, and edit the `grub.cfg` file to add some lines like

```
menuentry '[loopback]ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64' {
    set isofile='/boot/iso/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile locale=en_US.UTF-8
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

[`linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi` may need to be `linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz`, and I've used it successfully without "`locale=en_US.UTF-8`"]

and then boot Ubuntu from the ISO on your hard drive.

If you wanted to overwrite the partition that holds the ISO, you would probably need more than 2GB of ram, and the extra boot/kernel option `toram` (added to the `linux (loop)...` line), then the whole ISO would be copied & run from ram, letting you overwrite your hard drive all you want.

For more info:

- [ArchWiki on Multiboot USB drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Ubuntu) - Oriented towards making a USB, but if GRUB works on your hard drive the same principles should apply

But it would probably be easier to pick up a cheap DVD-R or DVD-RW, or an ultra-cheap 2GB USB drive, and make a new bootable Ubuntu DVD/USB.

Comment: Do I need to create a new partition?

Comment: That's where it could be tricky, if there's enough ram I'd use `toram`, then you don't worry about whether the iso's on the Ubuntu partition you want to overwrite. Or even if it is on there, as long as it stays mounted then the installer *might* leave the iso file alone while it installs, but I'm not sure. Putting the iso on the Windows partition might work too, if there's already a Windows entry in GRUB that you could "copy" the location from, getting GRUB to load on different partitions can be tricky

Comment: My pc has 2gb ram is that enough for 'toram'?

Comment: It might be enough, I'm not sure how much ram the installer uses

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would download the minimal CD and install that. From there, set up your internet and you can download a desktop environment pretty easily from the command line. It may be easier to use an ethernet cable if you can, in case setting up wifi gives you trouble. Or maybe you set up a restore point long ago?

Minimal CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD